# How to calculate slope in matlab?

Tags: matlab

is it possible to get slope of every grid of `80*80*37` (latitude, longitude, time(in years))matrix.?

i tried using `polyfit` function on `matlab` for it, was stuck 
as i didn't  know what exactly to put as `x` and `y`, as what i was putting was giving error. if i am putting `gradient` function again on `matlab`,

```
[dx,dy]=gradient(x)
```

what i am getting is value of `dx` and `dy`. but i don't know what the slope is using this.
so, i really need help to find  slope of every grid in my `80*80*37 matrix` in `matlab`

Comment: I suspect...it is not slope....it might be grid resolution...please check your purpose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although the question is not very clear, I am going to assume that you want an 80x80 matrix with each element being the slope along the time dimension, assuming you have a linear dependence. And I am assuming you have a vector containing the years.

```
% dimensions
latit = 80;
longit = 80;
time = 37; % number of years

years = 1900:1936; % the vector of years

% randomly generated data
A = rand(latit, longit, time);

% matrix to hold the slopes
slopes = zeros(latit, longit);
for i=1:latit
    for j=1:longit
        p = polyfit(years, reshape(A(i, j, :), 1, []),1);
        slopes(i, j) = p(1);
    end
end
```

In the future, please make the questions more clear, and try to include as much information and data as needed for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thank you for the response, actually i was very much confused while asking the question. Therefore, could not provide the sufficient information. I will care care of that in future